# Python Pandas Dataframe Value Replace Using Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with some values

```
   Country     Score
0  USA          8

1  India[In]    7

3  Canada[cn]   Nothing

4  Africa[Af]   Nothing
```

I want to reformat the `DataFrame` to look like this

```
   Country     Score
0  USA          8

1  India        7

3  Canada       0

4  Africa       0
```

- How can I format the county name to remove the bracket part?
- How can I replace all the unavailable values of core Column with 0?

Any help, please

Comment: country, replace `\[.*?\]` with empty. score replace `Nothing` with `0`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to safely manipulate values of a column is by using a helper function and [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) on the column

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(your_data)

def remove_brackets(string):
    brak_start = string.find('[')
    if brak_start == -1:  #We didn't find it
        return string
    else:  #Cut the string 
        return string[:brak_start]

data.Country.apply(remove_brackets)
```

To replace `NaN` values in a dataframe, use [`df.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```py
data.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `str.replace`

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace('\[.*\]','')
df['Score'] = df['Score'].str.replace('Nothing','0').astype(int)

print(df)

  Country  Score
0     USA      8
1   India      7
3  Canada      0
4  Africa      0
```

Comment: Sure, I will. One more help can you explain how will this function call replace('\[.*\]','') work?

Comment: .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) @sudhirkaushik see [here](https://regex101.com/r/1uN51b/1)